# Reading a List in Python

Tags: python

Hey I am trying to read two txt files. One is a list, another is master file. When a word in the list matches a word in the masterfile, I want to print the line the word is on, the line before the word that it matches and the line after. Below is the current code. I can only seem to figure out how to print the line after

```
import os 
os.chdir(r"XXXX DF")
def createlist():
    items = []
    with open('phrases.txt') as input:
        for line in input:
            items.extend(line.strip().split(','))
    return items

print(createlist())
# store the list
word_list = createlist()

with open('January 19.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
    # split the file content to words (first to lines, then each line to it's words)
     for word in line.strip().split():
        # check if each word is in the list
        if word in word_list:
            # do something with word
            print (word, end= '')
            #Print next line 
            print(next(f))
            #Print next line 
        else:
            StopIteration
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember each line, in case the *next* one matches.

```
prev = None
for line in f:
    # split the file content to words (first to lines, then each line to it's words)
    for word in line.strip().split():
        # check if each word is in the list
        if word in word_list:
            # Print the previous line, matching word, and next line
            print(prev)
            print(word, end= '')
            print(next(f))
    prev = line   # Remember the current line in case of a later match
```

---

This doesn't work well if your matching words are in consecutive lines.
Also note that your line iterating is inconsistent: you "magically" grab an extra line within your loop.  A more general way to handle this is to keep a buffer of lines, and check the middle one for a matching word:

```
buffer = [None, None, next(f)]  Put the first line into the buffer
for line in f:
    buffer = buffer[1:] + [line]   # shift the buffer; add next line
    # Check the buffer's middle line for a match
    # split the file content to words (first to lines, then each line to it's words)
    for word in buffer[1].strip().split():
        # check if each word is in the list
        if word in word_list:
            # Print the matching line and adjacent lines
            print(buffer)
            break
```

You still have a special case or two to test and check; I leave that as an exercise for the student.  However, it's more flexible.